# How can I do so that bottom border of my svg image will change when I press the button in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, border

[So here is my animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C94Mj.jpg)

As you can see, the bottom border is circular, but I need it to change to the normal one when I press on my svg image. And I need to make it only for the bottom border. I tried to do so just by creating a hook:

```
const [isRoundBorder, setIsRoundBorder] = useState(1);
```

And then writing a conditional rendering:

```
isRoundborder ?
   Whatever :
   Whatever
```

[But here is what is happening if I do so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmazQ.jpg)

So it looks bad. How can I improve this in React Native?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a negative top margin and zIndex to the dropdown section of your component. Make sure the text and + button are still visible. This what you don't need the is rounded border state.